# Android App Crashes in Release Mode using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

My app (built in Visual Studio 2022 using Xamarin) is using Firebase, and when a Release version is deployed to a device, the app crashes immediately with a " firebaseinitprovider not found". However when the debug version is deployed to the same device everything works fine.

What have I missed out?

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled?

Comment: I am not using proguard. With some experimenting I discovered if  I set the code shrinker to blank (instead of r8) the app runs fine.